# Type safe access to SObject ChildRelationships describe

Tags: apex, describesobject

To access an `SObjectField` you can use `Account.Field_Name__c`.  This has the advantage of being checked at compile time.  Is there an equivalent syntax for [ChildRelationship](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_ChildRelationship.htm#apex_class_Schema_ChildRelationship)?

`Account.Contacts` does not compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There is no way to get the child relationship without looping. As far as I know this is the only approach to getting a specific `ChildRelationship`:

```
ChildRelationship specificRelationship;
for (ChildRelationship relation : SObjectType.MyObject__c.getChildRelationships())
{
    if (relation.getField() == ChildObject__c.Parent__c)
    {
        specificRelationship = relation;
        break;
    }
}
```

However, in cases where I have needed to reference them repeatedly it has been expedient to make some sort of describe cache. Below is one simple example:

```
public with sharing class DescribeCache
{
    static Map<SObjectType, Map<SObjectField, ChildRelationship>> relationships =
        new Map<SObjectType, Map<SObjectField, ChildRelationship>>();

    public static ChildRelationship get(SObjectType parentType, SObjectField childField)
    {
        if (!relationships.contains(parentType))
        {
            // cache relationships
        }
        return relationships.get(parentType).get(childField);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was afraid that was the case....  I have a method where I'm trying to pass them in, which means the best I can do is have the signature accept a `string` and check it at runtime. :(

Answer (score 2):

You could make a reference to the lookup itself, i.e. `Contact.AccountId`. You can get the child relationship name from the [describe of that](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_methods_system_fields_describe).

Comment: nice, I actually hadn't thought of that.  I wonder if that would work with Activities (EG: `Task.WhoId`)...

Comment: Good question. My best guess is that with polymorphic lookups (which are always standard), the child relationship name is constant across all types it can look up to.

Comment: One weakness of this is, the field token oddly doesn't actually contain a reference to climb back up to the object token. So in some cases you still might need to wrap the object and field token together in order to calculate everything you need to know about this child relationship from the parent's perspective.

Comment: ya, I was thinking the same thing at the polymorphic relationship, I'll test it out.  Wouldn't `getReferenceTo()` give you the parent `SObjectType`?

Comment: oh wait... not if it's polymorphic...

Comment: Not exactly what I was saying. Suppose we are talking about the Contact-Account relationship. You can represent it by the field token `SObjectField sof = Contact.AccountId`. If you use `sof.getDescribe().getReferenceTo()` you can get a reference to the token for `Account`. What you can't do is navigate from the token back to `Contact`. So if you are working with the Account object and you use `Contact.AccountId` to represent the child relationship to Contacts, you can figure out from that token that the child relationship is named `Contacts` but not that the object it points to is `Contact`.

Comment: So I goofed. `getRelationshipName()` gets the name you need to navigate up through this relationship child-to-parent, not parent-to-child. You still have to iterate through `getChildRelationships()` from the parent to get the reverse.